# How to design a circuit checking if 12V car battery is charging?

Tags: batteries, current, battery-charging, current-measurement

I have a small solar power charging module and load balancer, that takes input from a solar panel, has connectors for a car battery (12V) and output terminals.

These things are pretty common on thing like RVs, caravans, camper vans, etc.

The module however, has no digital readout displays. Attaching a couple of those to the terminals of the charger / power manager is trivial, but I was wondering how I can have an LED light up, when the car battery is charging, i.e. current is flowing *in to* the battery. And have no LED light up, when current is being drawn *from* the battery.

The Voltage / Amperage meters I use, just shows the absolute values, they don't display for instance a negative amp value to signify direction.

So, how / what would be the simplest circuit to display current direction, *in to* the battery (battery is being charged) and if current is drawn *from* the battery (battery is discharging)?

Obviously, the circuit should draw as little current as possible itself.

---

*Edit*

Couldn't I simply use a comparator, like an LM319, and use the batteries wire that connects its terminal to the power management unit as resistor? I.e. having the non-inverting input going to the battery terminal, and the inverting input to the power management box.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your current meter. It would be very unusual for a DC current meter not to provide an indication of the direction of the current it is measuring.

Comment: How much current? Charge current? Discharge current?

Comment: Get a DC current clamp meter, clamp the output of the solar panel or regulator - bingo! Result!

Comment: @Barry: I don't want to link to ebay pages, because it's discouraged here, but it's basically a 5€ V/A digital meter. It displays voltage and current, but the current doesn't go negative when the current changes direction. If the current would be displayed as negative when the batter is - say - discharging, that would be fine, but the meter displays positive current no matter the direction.

Comment: @DwayneReid Charge and discharge currents aren't too large, the battery is connected to the battery charger / power manager via a 20A fuse.

Comment: ACS712 + comparator.